# Static variables in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I need to define a variable and acces it like static variables in java. I want to acces this variable just by name of a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it inside of a companion object in your class

```
class Example {
    companion object { 
          val foo = 1
     }
}

Example.foo
```

If everything inside of your class is going to be static then you can make that class an object in Kotlin

```
object Example {

        val foo = 1
 }

Example.foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make companion object inside that class here is example using RoomDatabase Aechitecture components

```
class MyDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

companion object {

        var instance: MyDatabase? = null
    }
```